# How do I remove text after a specific character in tableau?

Tags: character, tableau-api

I need to remove everything after a specific character in `tableau`.
E.g.

`xx.xxx.xxx.xxx` will become `xx.xxx`, similarly if I have `xxx.xxx.xx.xx` it will become `xxx.xxx`. Basically I want to remove everything after the second `.`.

I have tried the below but it doesn't work.

```
IF CONTAINS([Dimension], '.') THEN
MID(
    [Dimension],
    FIND([Dimension],'.') + 1,
    FIND([Dimension],'.',2) - (FIND([Dimension],'.') +1)
)
END
```

I am getting Null when moving my calculated field in the rows part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula should do it:

```
LEFT([Dimension], FINDNTH([Dimension],".",2)-1)
```

Comment: Good solution to this specific problem, but be aware that the regular expression functions, such as REGEXP_REPLACE(), are also useful - and can handle  more complex string pattern matching and replacement tasks. Many data sources support the REGEXP functions but not all.